Dataframe - Count the frequency of variables in three columns with similar(same) variables in
I have a dataframe, where I split the string variables in to new columns as they were in one column as strings and separated by a ','.
Now I would like to count the three columns and aggregate the frequency of each variable.
The below is the code I'm using to count the columns individually.
Split string into three columns
df6 = df5.join(
        df['Key Features'].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(
        columns={0:'Key Features A', 1:'Key Features B', 2:'Key Features C'}

      )
     )

Count Variables of individual columns
df8['Key Features A'].value_counts()
df8['Key Features B'].value_counts()
df8['Key Features C'].value_counts()

'''
Thanks!

read notice:[mre]

Thanks, I will follow the guidelines, but I do think the way I wrote this is clear? Please provide guidance of where it isn't if not. :)

The guidance is in the link. You should provide a small sample (e.g. via df.to_dict()) and also add the desired / expected output based on that sample.

If I understand what you require: each value_counts() is a Dictionary and you want to combine the 3 Dictionaries by adding the count values. If so the function show below does that with a simple example:
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1],
                  'y': [1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1],
                  'z': [2, 3, 4, 1, 1,  1, 1]
                  })

x= df['x'].value_counts()
y = df['y'].value_counts()
z = df['z'].value_counts()

def combine(*a):
    s = {}
    for b in a:
        for k, v in b.items():
            s[k] = s.get(k,0) + v
    return s
    
print(combine(x, y, z))

gives:
{1: 9, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1}

which is Dictionary showing the total counts.

If this is apparently what the OP wants (I do not get that from the Q in current state, but given the acceptance of the answer), one can just do: df.stack().value_counts().

@ouroboros1 Good suggestion. I assumed the question was about combining Dictionaries rather than Pandas code to give the total counts.
